# Windows 10 on Dell Inspiron N5050 boots to non-existent display

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, dell-inspiron

I am helping someone with their Dell Inspiron N5050, which has Windows 10 installed on it.  The computer will boot up, but I only get a black screen.  I did find, that if I closed the lid, reopened, and press the power button, I will get the login screen, and can use Windows 10 normally.  However, you have to repeat this process every time.

I found out that the computer boots to a non-existent display on a hunch.  I decided to plug in a second monitor, and got the login screen on that second monitor.  I then disconnected the monitor, rebooted, went through the process above, and saw only one display listed in Display Properties.  However, when I hit Detect, it listed two monitors.

I did try to fix this with the following:

1. Going into Device Manager, and uninstalling Generic PnP Monitor.
2. Disabling the "Quick Restart" option in Power Options > Decide What the Power Button Does.
3. Checking BIOS for switchable graphics, but there are no video options in BIOS for this laptop.
4. Checking the Intel Display Properties, but found no relevant setting.

I've also looked at various forums and guides online, but they seem to suggest the same things as fix #2.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Have you tried `windows` + `p`?

Comment: When I hit those keys, the screen did not change.  I tried to type the password in, but nothing changed.  When I went through the process above to get to the prompt, it said wrong password.  I don't think this will be acceptable to the person I'm doing this for.

Thanks though.

Comment: Tried again, to no effect.  It seems that no matter what I type after `windows` + `p`, the screen remains blank.  I type in the password, and either get "Wrong password", or nothing happened.  I tried hitting the `down arrow` to get the log in prompt, and type the password, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the device manufacturer website hasn`t released the Windows 10 compatible drivers for your model machine. We may need to revert back to previous version to make the device work well.

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15-intel-n5050/drivers

Comment: Nice find, I wonder if getting the drivers direct from Intel would help...

Comment: You are correct, Dell doesn't have any drivers for Intel HD 3000 Graphics.  I discovered the reason behind this; Intel hasn't produced them for Windows 10.

I tried uninstalling the drivers for that adapter, and got mixed results.  Windows 10 did boot up to the laptop display, and show the me login prompt.  However, it did so after taking much longer to load, with a max resolution of 1024x768.  I'm sure the individual wouldn't mind the low resolution, but would complain about the insane load time.

I did reinstall the drivers, but the problem resurfaced immediately too.

Comment: From @Map's link there is a Dell article about installing Win8.1 drivers on Win10. http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN297952